# Spritesheet in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm currently making a pokerapplication, and I found a spritesheet with images of cards. But i have no idea how to show only part of that picture with XAML. Can anybody help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200604/in-wpf-view-a-portion-of-an-image

Answer (score 1):

Create a helper class that will take your spritesheet bitmap and generate new bitmaps from it as required.

Here is an example:

http://taylorza.blogspot.co.uk/2009/08/silverlight-spritesheet-management-with.html