# How to show some percentage height of an image?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
<Image x:Name="pageImg" Margin="24,-1,37,19" Source="img\verses\67_ (11).png" Stretch="Uniform"  />
```

How to set for example `95` percent of an image be displayed?

Comment: @RvdK Thats unrelated. The "percentage" mentioned in this question is refering to the size of the image before being stretched.

Comment: @Vlad Just to clarify: If the Image's size is 1000x1000 you want the WPF image to be 950x950?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Let's assume the image is 1000*500px. I want to image be displayed just from height 0 to 950. The last 50px be removed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is a cropped bitmap:

```
<Image>
  <Image.Source>
    <CroppedBitmap Source="<path to source image>" SourceRect="10,10,10,10"/>
  </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

The parameters in SourceRect determine the starting point and the area that is being viewed.

Source:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.croppedbitmap(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Apologies for the answer to a duplicate. I wasn't aware of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200604/in-wpf-view-a-portion-of-an-image